# Porting code to Pharo 2.0

Tags: stream, smalltalk, pharo

[Pharo 2.0](http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download/release-2-0) changed some basic API bits, and I cannot found the new way of doing the following:

1. `FileDirectory default directoryNamed: aFolderString.`
2. `FileDirectory on: aFilename.`
3. `FileDirectory default assureExistenceOfPath: aString.`
4. `ReferenceStream on: stream.`

What would be the new equivalent code? 
Is there an update guide available describing how to translate or port code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have collected some translations you may find useful:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                    FileDirectory                     |                                FileSystem                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FileDirectory assureExistence.                       | aString asFileReference ensureDirectory.                                  |
| FileDirectory baseNameFor: aString.                  | aString asFileReference base.                                             |
| FileDirectory containingDirectory.                   | Path parent asFileReference pathString.                                   |
| FileDirectory default deleteFileNamed: aString.      | aString asFileReference ensureDeleted.                                    |
| FileDirectory default directoryExists: aString.      | aString asFileReference exists.                                           |
| FileDirectory default directoryNamed: aFolderString. | FileSystem disk / aFolderString.                                          |
| FileDirectory directoryEntryFor: aString.            | aString asFilereference.                                                  |
| (FileDirectory entryFor: aString) / 'filename'.      | aString asFileReference / 'filename'.                                     |
| FileDirectory extensionFor: aString.                 | aString asFileReference extension.                                        |
| FileDirectory default fileExists: aString.           | aString asFileReference exists. " or " DiskStore current isFile: aString. |
| FileDirectory default fullNameFor: aString.          | aString asFileReference fullName.                                                         |
| FileDirectory default pathName.                      | FileSystem disk workingDirectory fullName.                                |
| FileDirectory on: aFilename.                         | aFilename asFileReference.                                                |
| (FileDirectory on: aString) entries collect: #name.  | aString asFileReference children collect: #basename.                      |
| (FileDirectory on: aString) entryAt: 'filename'.     | aString asFileReference / 'filename'.                                     |
| FileDirectory oldFileNamed: aString.                 | aString asFileReference readStream.                                       |
| FileDirectory slash.                                 | FileSystem disk separator. " or " DiskStore delimiter asString.           |
+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 13):

The following statements correspond do the ones you put in your question.

1. `FileSystem workingDirectory / aFolderString`
2. `aFilename asFileReference`
3. `aString asFileReference ensureDirectory`
4. ReferenceStream does no longer exist in 2.0.

`aPathString asFileReference` resolves `aPathString`, so if there are slashes in your name you will end up in a subdirectory.

`/` on the other hand takes a single directory or file name as an argument, and does not resolve further subdirectories. Depending on your platform you can easily refer to a file named `foo/bar` with a slash in the name with `FileSystem workingDirectory / 'foo/bar'`.

Answer (score 5):

ReferenceStream is not supported anymore and has been deleted in Pharo 2.0. You should use Fuel which is well written, well documented, well tested and very fast. http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/web/pier/software/Fuel

Comment: I don't mean to troll you but your answer is not answering the question (it's appropriate as comment to the question though)

Comment: Besides if you use Fuel to materialize a ReferenceStream, you will get a FLBadSignature exception